# Fancyhdr not working

Tags: fancyhdr

I follow a template for an academic journal. I would like to have in the even pages the name of the authors in the heading and in the odd page the title of the paper. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter\if@twocolumn\PassOptionsToPackage{switch}{lineno}\else\fi\makeatother


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsbsy,amssymb,tabulary,graphicx,times,caption,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=6.5in,margin=2cm,headsep=.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewenvironment{abstract} {\vspace*{-1pc}\trivlist\item[]\leftskip\oupIndent\hrulefill\par\vskip4pt\noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\mbox{\null}\\}{\par\noindent\hrulefill\endtrivlist} 
\linespread{1.13} \date{}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=sc,skip=1.4pt,aboveskip=1pc}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sc,skip=1.4pt,labelsep=newline}


\makeatletter\def\oupIndent{1pt}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{\hskip-\dimexpr(\tabcolsep)\hskip\oupIndent\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\oupIndent}{\centering\bfseries#1}}}
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\centering\bfseries\ifx\@articleType\@empty\else\@articleType\\\fi#1}}
\let\@articleType\@empty \def\articletype#1{\gdef\@articleType{{\normal\itshape#1}}}
\fancypagestyle{headings}
{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[RO]{\RunningHead}\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage \,\ \textbullet \,\ \Running}}\pagestyle{headings}
\makeatother

\tolerance=400
\usepackage{url,multirow,morefloats,floatflt,cancel,tfrupee}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\title{Our paper}
\author{\textbf{\fontsize{14pt}{16.4pt}\selectfont{Auth1\textsuperscript{1,2}\textsuperscript{,*}, Auth2\textsuperscript{1}, and Auth3\textsuperscript{1}}}~\\\normalsize\normalfont 
~\\\textsuperscript{1}{Our Department \unskip, Our University \unskip, Our address \unskip, Our city\unskip, Postcode\unskip, Our country. 
    Tel.:~+11 1111111}
~\\\textsuperscript{2}{His School\unskip, His University\unskip, His address \unskip, His city \unskip, Country. 
    Tel.:~his number}~\\{\normalsize\normalfont *Corresponding E-mail: auth@email}~\\{\normalsize\normalfont  E-mails: email1 (auth1); email3 (auth3)}}
\def\RunningHead{{Our paper}}
\def\Running{{Auth1, Auth2, Auth3}}

\maketitle 

\section{Section1}
\lipsum
\section{Section2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Apparently, I cannot obtain what I need. It seems that I can only have the same heading into all page.

Any help on how I can fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: article is oneside by default, just there is no distinction between even and odd. Try adding the `twoside` class options to see the difference.

Comment: @daleif. Thanks!

Comment: @daleif Can you make this as answer? So others can know if they facing this kind of situation...

Comment: @MadyYuvi done.

Comment: @daleif Much thanks for this...

Comment: @Dario Please accept the answer (if it meets your expectation), by clicking the tick mark...

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. I forgot. Just done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup for fancyhdr depends on having a distinction between odd and even pages. But the default in the article class is `oneside` aka all pages behaves as odd pages.

Add the `twoside` class option to see the difference.